# Java - Oracle - XML TimeZone

Tags: java, linux, oracle, datetime, timezone

I have an issue related with the timezone that I'm not able to solve. Maybe someone here can give me a hand. I will try to explain the scenario:

I have 2 servers:

- Windows Server 2008: this is the application server in which I have a web service running over an Apache Tomcat 6.29. The JVM installed is 1.6_20
- Linux Red Hat Enterprise: this is the DB server which has intalled an Oracle database server 11.1.0.6.0

Both servers have the timezone UTC+2 (CAIRO) and show the same time.
By other hand the web service that is running in the windows server is developed with Java and Apache CXF (JAX-WS + JAXB). All the dates and times returned by the WS are got from the DB and I use annotations to marshall the dates to XML format. Examples of WS responses:

```
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected Date birthDate;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected Date activationDate;
```

The problem I have is that some of these dates are returned by the WS with timezone +02:00 and some others with timezone +03:00, and I'm not able to find an explanation.

As far as I know the timezone is set by java taking the proper value from the OS, I'm not sure but I think Oracle does not store the timezone of a date, correct me If I'm wrong. So, from my understanding all the dates should come with the same timezone.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have oracle store the timezone, it's not something we do here but it is possible.

These two links may help you out.
[TIMESTAMP with local time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169) and 
[NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1007035)

Comment: Thats means that if I use timestamps with timezone and I instantiate a date in java with a date coming from DB then the timezone will be the one stored in DB? Or java will use the one of the OS?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, as I said we don't do that here, but I imagine that you will have to change the java.util.date to a java.sql.timestamp and when the web service pulls the timestamp from the DB then you have to create the timestamp using the method ResultSet.getTimstamp(String column,Calendar cal) to have the timestamp with the correct timezone. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(java.lang.String, java.util.Calendar)

Comment: In fact I already use Timestamps instead of dates. I realized a issue related with the daylight saving deactivation (we are in cairo where there isn't daylight saving) in Red Hat Linux, I installed an update and now the dates returned are all coming with +3, at least are the same but it is supposed should be +2.